How do I show data from a spreadsheet? it shows "undefined"
I've been checked for more than half a day now. I am totally blanked right now! I don't know where am I missing something? Please help me. My .gs code (Google Script) is below
function readRecords() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const headers = data[0];
  return data.slice(1).map(row => {
    return headers.reduce((record, header, idx) => ({ ...record, [header]: row[idx] }), {});
  });
}

My code with HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <title>Show Records</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="recordsContainer"></div>

    <script>
      function displayRecords(records) {
        const container = document.getElementById('recordsContainer');
        container.innerHTML = '';
        if (records.length === 0) {
          container.innerHTML = '<p>No records found.</p>';
          return;
        }

        const table = document.createElement('table');
        table.classList.add('table');
        const thead = table.createTHead();
        const row = thead.insertRow();
        Object.keys(records[0]).forEach(header => {
          const th = document.createElement('th');
          th.textContent = header;
          row.appendChild(th);
        });

        const tbody = table.createTBody();
        records.forEach(record => {
          const row = tbody.insertRow();
          Object.values(record).forEach(value => {
            const td = row.insertCell();
            td.textContent = value;
          });
        });

        container.appendChild(table);
      }

      function fetchRecords() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayRecords).readRecords();
      }

      window.onload = fetchRecords;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

Where is my problem and what am I missing? Please help me:
The image showing the "undefined"

The console


Uncaught TypeError: container is null



Is there anything else in the logs? Could you add different console.log("Step 1") at different places and see where it fails?  2. Have you changed getValues() to getDisplayValues() as @Tanaike suggested?


Just to reiterate my comment yesterday. Can you share what your data looks like? Because I have tested this code and it is working on my end. The only change I did on OP's code is just getting the Sheet name and the Spreadsheet to work on. I am thinking 2 things as source of the issue, the value being taken from Google Sheet, which should be addressed by @Tanaike's suggestion. 2. From the complete code you have posted yesterday, did you change the Name of the Sheet values or is it really what your code looks like?

You can fetch google spreadsheet data like this, need to add your spreadsheetId, range and apiKey.
your spreadsheetId is the long number that appears after "d/" in the URL.
range is like A3:D or sheetname!A1:A3.
And you can get apiLey from https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard.
 async function fetchSheetData() {
 const url = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadsheetId}/values/${range}?       key=${apiKey}`;
 
   try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
          if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
        }
         const data = await response.json();
         
         } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      }
    }


I'm trying thiss code but it not work.Can you have another without api?

I've also used this code in a project and It works fine. Do you face any problem in it?

I found the error need to open anyone can see before use the API.Thank you very much
